# Index prefix doesn't work if a compound index contains 2dsphere index

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-indexes, 2dsphere

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({x: 1, location: '2dsphere'})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.test.find({x: 0}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 100009,
        "nscanned" : 100009,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 100009,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 100009,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 781,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 40,
        "server" : "hackintosh:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

MongoDB Version: 2.6.2

I created a compound index on `x` and `location`, but when I queried on `x`, why it didn't work?

Comment: Your documents with {x:0} has no geospatial fields ?

Comment: I would suspect that this is a known quirk, there is most likely a JIRA for it somewhere

Comment: @kranteg All the docs have location fields.

Comment: Maybe [SERVER-9257](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9257) @Sammaye? Though, this was supposedly fixed in 2.5.4

Comment: @elhoyos that looks it indeed, so it should work now

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your document  doesn't have the `location` key or the `location` is null so your query will not use that index unless explicitly hinted.

That's probably because 2dsphere indexes in MongoDB 2.6 are sparse. You can use `hint()` to explicitly specify the index, but even then you will not find the documents without the `location` field because they will not be added to the index.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#sparse-property):

> If a document lacks a 2dsphere index field (or the field is null or an
>   empty array), MongoDB does not add an entry for the document to the
>   2dsphere index. For inserts, MongoDB inserts the document but does not
>   add to the 2dsphere index.
>
> For a compound index that includes a 2dsphere index key along with
>   keys of other types, only the 2dsphere index field determines whether
>   the index references a document.

If you really have to find documents by it's `x` field whether `loc` is set or not I would suggest adding a separate index (non-sparse index) just for that field.

**Edit**

I did some additional testing. In this case it seems that MongoDB will always default to using `BasicCursor`, unless you explicitly specify the index with a [hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/). Like Sammaye said, it's probably a known quirk.

Comment: All the docs have `location` key, index still doesn't work :(

Comment: @user805627 having a location key is not sufficient, the field must be non null... see my update.